# Rails 4 - Delayed_Job for CSV import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm building a marketplace app in Rails 4 where sellers can list items to sell. I have a csv import feature so sellers can bulk load products. The import code worked fine on small files but I ran into timeout issues with larger files. So I want to use delayed_job to process these files in the background.

I set up delayed_job up to the point where the job is queued (i see the job in the delayed_job table). But when I run the job, I get an error saying that the file to be imported is not found. It is looking for the file in a temp folder which doesn't exist when the job is run.

How do I save (or without saving) the file in a location where delayed_job can access it? And how to I tell delayed_job where the file is located?

my listings controller:

```
  def import
      Listing.import(params[:file], params[:user_id])
      redirect_to seller_url, notice: "Products are being imported."
  end
```

my listing model:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

  class << self

    def importcsv(file_path)
        CSV.foreach(file_path, headers: true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|
          #some model processing
        end 
    end 
    handle_asynchronously :importcsv
  end

  # My importer as a class method
  def self.import(file, user_id)
    Listing.importcsv file.path
  end

end
```

Here is form view:

```
<%= form_tag import_listings_path, multipart: true do %>
        <%= file_field_tag :file %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
        <%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the file is a form upload.  I think those files only persist while the web request is running.  My recommendation is to use FileUtils.copy to copy the file into some location that will exist when your job runs.
So, probably you don't want to handle_asynchronously  importcsv, but instead copy the files then call a private method on your model (which will be handled asynchronously) with the new file paths.

Comment: I just added the form view while you were writing your answer. You are right. Can you tell me how to do this?